# Did Caulifla learn super saiyan and super saiyan 2 in the same day?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

Note: we're already in episode 98 of Dragon Ball Super, yet, if it's considered this topic has to be hidden with the spoilers invisible tag, edit the parts you consider relevant.

**Details from episode 92 and 93 behind**:

In episode 92 of Dragon Ball Super Cabba teachs Caulifla how to turn into Super Saiyan. And in episode 93, Caulifla, to save Cabba from Kale's attack turns into Super Saiyan 2. Is this supposed to happen all in the same day? Did Caulifla actually learn super saiyan 2 by her own and in the same day she learnt super saiyan?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid this is becoming a habit on Dragonball Super questions, but the current answer as of Episode 98 is that *we do not know*.

The Saiyans from Universe 6 don't seem to have names for their forms. One could guess that is because they're currently only Super Saiyans - just as we didn't have the name Super Saiyan 2, or Ascended Saiyan until our Universe 7 Saiyans reached those forms.

Outside of the Universe 6 Saiyans saying "I feel I've reached a level above Super Saiyan"/"I feel I can change form again!" or a Universe 7 character saying "I can't believe you've already reached Super Saiyan 2!" we won't know for sure.

I would say we'll need to stop using Aura's as proof of forms. Not only do we not know if the Universe 6 Saiyan transformation is completely analogous to Universe 7 (since Universe 7 Saiyans never transformed by focusing on a single spot on their back), we also have seen Goku and Vegeta create a Ki-Aura to stop Lavender's poison attack yet was thought in at least one question on this site to be some new form. Plus, IRL we have the animators using new animation styles - they may just like using lightning around Caulifla to visually represent how she is a "cut above" the average Super Saiyan even in base form.

Edit: as of episode 100, we have Caulifla specifically say she went Super Saiyan 2 in the same day however she did say that she was unable to return to that form until Goku went Super Saiyan 2 to show her, so I'd say she didn't "learn" Super Saiyan 2 on that day. This is backed up by her going into what a Dragonball Wiki calls [Super Saiyan Third Grade](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Super_Saiyan_Third_Grade) (The big-muscle "power but no speed" SSJ form) instead of going SSJ2 - just like when Goku and Trunks did when they hadn't reached SSJ2.

Comment: There is another teased picture of Caulifla for upcoming episodes where she has a sort of "buff form" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K6pWH_M5ctc

Comment: there is a writer in Twitter from Dragon Ball Super with only a little over a thousand followers. We could ask him I guess?

Comment: This is a writer from Dragon Ball Super https://twitter.com/toshio916

Comment: ok, if there was any doubt it was confirmed at the preview of Dragon Ball Super  episode 100 with words from Goku that Caulifla it is a Super Saiyan 2.

Comment: @Pablo Does my edit (now we have episode 100) better answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

While there is no "official" answer, based on how the power up went and what we know about transformation we can assume it was a super saiyan 2.
Super has taken an "casual" way with both character transformations and power ups, where basically everyone has gotten an crazy boost, including master roshi.Even if you look at the 7 universe, both Goten and Trunks could do a ssj transformation without any problem.

If you look at the build of the saiyans from  the 6 universe, they are much smaller then the saiyans from the 7 universe and yet their base strength seems to be incedibly high. Cabbas base strength was same as Vegetas(and he seems to be much younger), and we know how much Vegeta has trained to achieve that power. When then you account how fast they seem to learn things, i think its safe to assume that they are "biologically superior" to the 7 universe saiyans.

Comment: well the question was more about if all happened in one day than if Caulifla was super saiyan 2 or not. I thought that was a settled debate among fans, but for the former answer aparently not.

Comment: yeah it happend on the same, they were all there at the same time and the conversation was flowing seemlesly. Caulifla seems to be the most talented saiyan we saw so far

Comment: It's being teased that she's going to ask Goku to teach her to transform into Super Saiyan Blue. So now everybody is speculating if she is going to achieve that in the tournament or not. Personally I would prefer she wont, it wont make sense if she learns a complicated and powerful transformation so fast. A few days ago she couldnt even turn into a super saiyan. I can take it if they make it transform into SSJ3 but Blue seems too much for her to learn so quickly.

Comment: I know where you are comming from, but since she mastered ssj 2 so fast, most likely without even realizing it, to me it seems she will be able to master the blue form with relative ease as well. She is just a "genius", so with little effort she can master "hard" things.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think she will get Super Saiyan Blue but they are in another dimension and that leads me to think she's going to achieve Super Saiyan 3.

As of the latest DBS episode she achieved SSJ2 the same way she achieved SSJ which leads me to believe they're doing a cop out to how Super Saiyan forms work.

They were originally based on anger felt intensely. So if anger is the trigger for all Saiyan transformations and the tingly back thing just happens while they're intensely angry.

Much like how people under high stress tend to get back pain.

It can be speculated that simply training in SSJ1 making the form easier to hold. Then gaining more power while training in SSJ1 will give you the needed push if you were to do the "tingly back thing" with your kei/chi energy's to transform into SSJ2... which was what Caulifla just did in episode 100.

So having only Goku and Gotenks to go on for SSJ3 other dimension or not.. it seems very likely that Caulifla is going to attain SSJ3 but not have enough power to attain SSG/SSB. I wonder if Goku / Vegeta will tell them of the ritual however and bypass the training some time later or if it will just inspire the other Saiyans to train harder.

Comment: Goku mentioned that she could reach SSJ3 in the tournament. So I guess it's a hint that she will get there soon.